# Shared Preferences Deleting Data When App Is Reloaded

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating my first project using Android Studio, I am aiming to create an app where you can load photos in from the phones memory and display them so people can see.

I've managed to get it working sort of how I want it to, the pictures in the gallery stay where they should do when I close out of the app and then reopen it - however if I close the app restart it and then try and add a new photo it overwrites the gallery and deletes the pictures I orginally put in. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this? I tried playing with when I create the images ArrayList but that didn't help.

Code:

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 0;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAAGE = 1;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";

ImageView imageView;
Button uploadButton;
Button savedPhotos;
List<String> images;
String imageCreated;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    savedPhotos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    images = new ArrayList<>();

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAAGE);
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(imageCreated, "Complete");
        }
    });

    savedPhotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openPage2();
        }
    });


}

public void openPage2()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SavedPhotos.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                images.add(picturePath);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for(String i : images)
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(i);
                    stringBuilder.append(",");
                }
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("images", stringBuilder.toString() );
                editor.commit();

            }
    }
}}
```

And SavedPhotos

```
public class SavedPhotos extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_photos);
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    String wordsString = sharedpreferences.getString("images", "");
    String[] itemWords = wordsString.split(",");
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
    for(int i = 0; i < itemWords.length; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setId(i);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        layout.addView(imageView);
        items.add(itemWords[i]);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(items.get(i)));
    }
}}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually run to same issues before until i met a well made library and requires nothing and made my code much good looking, FastSave: https://github.com/yehiahd/FastSave-Android.